# Getting unexpected output using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am scraping a website and storing it in a database using `Pandas DataFrame`. There were no errors, but got weird output, as where the first column's row **ends**, the data inserted in the second column **starts** from there. Let me give you a visual example :

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
       x
       x
       x
                   x
                   x
                   x
                               x
                               x
                               x
```

So as you can see, the data is storing in this form inside `.csv` file as i stated the next data will fill where the previous one's end.

**Here is my code:**

```
    elements_1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(one_)

    web_content_list = []
    for ele in elements_1:
        web_content_dict = {}
        web_content_dict["Title"] = ele.text
        web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

    elements_2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(two_)

    for ele2 in elements_2:
        web_content_dict = {}
        web_content_dict["Title2"] = ele2.text
        web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

    elements_3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(three_)

    for ele3 in elements_3:
        web_content_dict = {}
        web_content_dict["Title3"] = ele3.text
        web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

    df = pd.DataFrame(web_content_list)
    df.to_csv(csv_file_location,
              index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```

> Also don't tell me to use `dropna()` or anything like that, cause this works when a file has null values, but in my case, it's not! So it won't work here...

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Are you trying to concat using append?

Comment: Yes! It works well when it has 1 column, but goes wierd with more than 1 col. As you can see in the post itself...

Comment: Your code is fundamentally flawed in that you're iteratively scraping a website column by column and using append on top of that. You should be appending row by row on a common structure instead.

Comment: Can you please show that in the code. 'cauz I don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..

If you just want dataframe with the following structure, post-processing would be proper.

Try this.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': df['Column 1'].dropna(),
              'Column 2': df['Column 2'].dropna(),
              'Column 3': df['Column 3'].dropna()})
```

Comment: Nah, it's still the same! @GilseungAhn